# mysql muliple joins from same colums with different keys

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, join, inner-join

I need some help making the second join with the tables below. I got some help from here previously where it was suggested I need to add a second JOIN, however, this is where I'm stuck and need some assistance.

**wp-posts**

```
  -----------------
  id | Post_Title | 
  -----------------
  01 | Event 1    | 
  -----------------
  02 | Event 2    | 
  -----------------
```

**wp-postmeta**

```
-------------------------------------------------------
  meta_id  | post_id | meta_key          | meta_value |
  -----------------------------------------------------
  456      | 01      | _EventStartDate   | 01/01/2017 |
  -------------------------------------------------- ---
  789      | 01      | _EventEndDate     | 05/02/2017 |
  -----------------------------------------------------
```

The end result I'm after is something like;

Title - starts on <_EventStartDate > and ends on <_EventEndDate>

and im using the following to get the data:

```
    $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "
SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID, $wpdb->posts.post_content, $wpdb->postmeta.meta_id, 

$wpdb->postmeta.post_id, $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key, $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value, $wpdb->posts.post_title 


FROM $wpdb->posts INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 

WHERE $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_EventStartDate' 

ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value " );
```

Now I've been told that the WHERE will just return a single row and that I need to make the second JOIN using `$wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_EventStartDate'` but after hours of trying to implement this I'm unable to get and data back at all.

If someone could help solve this it would be immensely helpful as I have a few more queries I would like to write and I'm guessing I will need to use the same principal with them too.

Thanks for reading!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a single inner join, grouping by the post ID and then splitting start date and end date:

```
select 
wpposts.post_content,
substring_index(GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value order by str_to_date(meta_value,'%d/%m/%Y')), ',', 1) as start_date ,
substring_index(GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value order by str_to_date(meta_value,'%d/%m/%Y')), ',', -1) as end_date
from wpposts inner join wppostmeta
on wpposts.id = wppostmeta.post_id
where wppostmeta.meta_key='_EventStartDate' or wppostmeta.meta_key='_EventEndDate'
group by wppostmeta.post_id
```

Comment: This did the job perfectly, thank you. if possible what lines 3 and 4 actually do? I'm assuming group by wppostmeta.post_id groups everything in the query by the post id?

Comment: No, the grouping is made by the last line; since you have two values for meta_value (for each group of records having same post_id), line 3-4 need to concat them (group_concat by default concat using ",") to make them available to the select part, then split them using substring_index, taking everything before the "," in line 3 (start_date) and everything after the "," in line 4 (end_date).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the start_date and end_date in one row using `group by` like this:

```
select
    t1.*,
    max(case when meta_key = '_EventStartDate' then meta_value end) start_date,
    max(case when meta_key = '_EventEndDate' then meta_value end) end_date
from wp_posts t1
inner join wp_postmeta t2
on t1.id = t2.post_id
group by t1.post_id;
```

if `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is enabled, change the group by clause to:

```
group by t1.post_id, t1.Post_title;
```

Comment: `^1` inspiring nice answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is only one `_EventStartDate` and one `_EventEndDate` per post in wp-postmeta, a simplified query would be:

```
SELECT p.post_title, pm1.meta_value AS start_date, pm2.meta_value AS end_date 
FROM wp-posts p 
     INNER JOIN wp-postmeta pm1
             ON  p.post_id     = pm1.post_id
            AND  pm1.meta_ekey = '_EventStartDate'  
     INNER JOIN wp-postmeta pm2
             ON  p.post_id     = pm2.post_id
            AND  pm2.meta_ekey = '_EventEndDate'
```