# PHP strtotime 'first day of this month' not returning the first day

Tags: php, mysql, strtotime

I'm currently using the script below to report back the events start and end date over the period of one month, hence using 'first day of this month' and 'last day of this month'

I've no idea why but any events that start on the first of March have note been included, any help as to why would be great. Thanks

```
 <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "

        SELECT

        $wpdb->posts.post_title,
        substring_index(GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value order by str_to_date(meta_value,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')), ',', 1) as start_date,
        substring_index(GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value order by str_to_date(meta_value,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')), ',', -1) as end_date

        FROM $wpdb->posts INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta

        ON $wpdb->posts.id = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id

        WHERE $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key='_EventStartDate' OR $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key='_EventEndDate'

        GROUP BY $wpdb->postmeta.post_id

        ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value

        " );

    foreach ( $result as $page ) {

        $date1 = new DateTime($page->start_date);
        $date2 = new DateTime($page->end_date);

        if (strtotime($page->start_date) >= strtotime('first day of this month') && strtotime($page->start_date) < strtotime('last day of this month')) {

            echo '<h2><div class="date-title">';
            echo $page->post_title;
            echo '</div><div class="date-date">';
            echo  '<span class="orderby">Order by ' . $date1->format('d-m-y') . '</span><span class="deliveryby"> For Delivery ' . $date2->format('d-m-y').'</span><br/>'; 
            echo '</div></h2>';
        }
    }     
?>
```

Comment: Since `print date('Y-m-d',strtotime('first day of this month'));` gives `2017-03-01` and you are not showing an expected and/or given data, no help possible.

Comment: there is no error other than that dates that start on the 01-03 are not included. if you look at the month view and change the start date to the second its appears but change it back to the first and it dissapears

Comment: this is the initial post i created to help to create the query - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41891324/mysql-muliple-joins-from-same-colums-with-different-keys - not sure if this is any help to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtotime()` uses the components of the current time for components it cannot find in the input string.

You don't specify a time of day in `"first day or this month"`, that's why `strtotime()` returns the correct date but with the current time:

```
echo(date('r', strtotime('first day of this month')));
# Wed, 01 Mar 2017 13:50:08 +0000
```

You can compare your page times  (`>=`) against

```
strtotime('first day of this month midnight')
```

and (`<`):

```
strtotime('first day of next month midnight')
```

to get the correct results.

```
echo(date("r", strtotime("last day of this month midnight")));
# Fri, 31 Mar 2017 00:00:00 +0000
echo(date("r", strtotime("first day of next month midnight")));
# Sat, 01 Apr 2017 00:00:00 +0000
```

If you also need to consider the timezone, I recommend you to avoid the old date&time PHP functions (they do not handle the timezone) and use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class instead:

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Bucharest');
$startMonth = new DateTime('first day of this month midnight', $timezone);
$endMonth   = new DateTime('first day of next month midnight', $timezone);

$startPage = new DateTime($page->start_date, $timezone);
$endPage   = new DateTime($page->end_date, $timezone);

if ($startMonth <= $startPage && $startPage < $endMonth) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation works but does not return midnight. Here is a better version with the comparison:

```
// what you are doing ->

$a = strtotime('first day of this month');
var_dump($a);

$a = strtotime('last day of this month');
var_dump($a);

// what you should be doing ->

$a = strtotime(date('Y-m-01'));
var_dump($a);

$a = strtotime(date('Y-m-t'));
var_dump($a);
```

->

```
int(1488376385) // UTC: 2017-03-01 13:53:05
int(1490968385) // UTC: 2017-03-31 13:53:05
int(1488326400) // UTC: 2017-03-01 00:00:00
int(1490918400) // UTC: 2017-03-31 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment on how you get data from db, I think you must create your dates from a different format like:

```
$firstDayOfThisMonth = new DateTime('first day of this month midnight');
$lastDayOfThisMonth = new DateTime('last day of this month midnight');

foreach ($result as $page) {
    $startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $page->start_date);
    $endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $page->end_date);

    if ($startDate >= $firstDayOfThisMonth  && $startDate < $lastDayOfThisMonth) {
        // do your stuff here
    }
}
```